# How come SO questions are not diggable?

Tags: feature-request, diggbar

How come SO questions and answers cannot be submitted to Digg?

---

(edit) Implied request: make SO work with the diggbar -- **if you are logged into digg** and click this link, you'll see what happens. http://digg.com/d1rhHa

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if Digg would like getting bombarded with every single SO question and answer that gets posted. I don't see what purpose it would really serve Digg or SO/SF/SU for that matter. If you are looking to get more eyes to your question, I could potentially see that...but by the time you submit something to Digg and it gets viewed by someone, your question is probably already dealt with by someone who is a user of StackOverflow itself.

Answer (score 2):

How does Stackoverflow preclude anyone from submitting a post to Digg?

[How to Submit a News Article to Digg.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_2031148_submit-news-article.html)

Comment: I think some framebusting code in SO breaks the diggbar, and that's what he's asking about.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well then, +1 for framebusting code.